# Aeropspike Kafka Outbound Connector - using map data type with Kafka Avro format

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, aerospike, cdc

Am trying to setup [Aerospike Kafka Outbound Connector](https://docs.aerospike.com/connect/kafka/from-asdb) (Source Connector) for Change Data Capture (CDC). When using Kafka Avro format for messages (as explained in https://docs.aerospike.com/connect/kafka/from-asdb/formats/kafka-avro-serialization-format), am getting following error from the connector:

```
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  | 2022-12-22 20:27:17.607 GMT INFO  metrics-ticker - requests-total: rate(per second) mean=8.05313731102431, m1=9.48698171570335, m5=2.480116641993411, m15=0.8667674157832074
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  | 2022-12-22 20:27:17.613 GMT INFO  metrics-ticker - requests-total: duration(ms) min=1.441459, max=3101.488585, mean=15.582822432504553, stddev=149.48409869767494, median=4.713083, p75=7.851875, p95=17.496458, p98=28.421125, p99=85.418959, p999=3090.952252
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  | 2022-12-22 20:27:17.624 GMT ERROR metrics-ticker - **java.lang.Exception - Map type not allowed, has to be record type**: count=184
```

My data contains a map field. The Avro schema for the data is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "mydata",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "metadata",
      "type": {
        "name": "com.aerospike.metadata",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "namespace",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "set",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "userKey",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "long",
              "double",
              "bytes",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "digest",
            "type": "bytes"
          },
          {
            "name": "msg",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "durable",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "boolean"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "gen",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "int"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "exp",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "int"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "lut",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "long"
            ],
            "default": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "test",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "testmap",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": "string",
        "default": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Has anyone tried and got this working?

**Edit:**

Looks like Aerospike connector doesn't support `map` type. I enabled verbose logging:

```
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  | 2023-01-06 18:41:31.098 GMT ERROR ErrorRegistry - Error stack trace
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  | java.lang.Exception: Map type not allowed, has to be record type
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.kafka.outbound.parser.KafkaAvroOutboundRecordGenerator$Companion.assertOnlyValidTypes(KafkaAvroOutboundRecordGenerator.kt:155)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.kafka.outbound.parser.KafkaAvroOutboundRecordGenerator$Companion.assertOnlyValidTypes(KafkaAvroOutboundRecordGenerator.kt:164)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.kafka.outbound.parser.KafkaAvroOutboundRecordGenerator$Companion.assertSchemaValid(KafkaAvroOutboundRecordGenerator.kt:101)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.kafka.outbound.parser.KafkaAvroOutboundRecordGenerator.<init>(KafkaAvroOutboundRecordGenerator.kt:180)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.kafka.outbound.inject.KafkaOutboundGuiceModule.getKafkaAvroStreamingRecordParser(KafkaOutboundGuiceModule.kt:59)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.kafka.outbound.inject.KafkaOutboundGuiceModule.access$getKafkaAvroStreamingRecordParser(KafkaOutboundGuiceModule.kt:29)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.kafka.outbound.inject.KafkaOutboundGuiceModule$bindKafkaAvroParserFactory$1.get(KafkaOutboundGuiceModule.kt:48)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.outbound.converter.XdrExchangeConverter.getInbuiltRecordFormatter(XdrExchangeConverter.kt:422)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.outbound.converter.XdrExchangeConverter.access$getInbuiltRecordFormatter(XdrExchangeConverter.kt:75)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.outbound.converter.XdrExchangeConverter$RouterAndInbuiltFormatter.<init>(XdrExchangeConverter.kt:285)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.outbound.converter.XdrExchangeConverter.processXdrRecord(XdrExchangeConverter.kt:192)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.outbound.converter.XdrExchangeConverter.parse(XdrExchangeConverter.kt:134)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at com.aerospike.connect.outbound.OutboundBridge$processAsync$1.invokeSuspend(OutboundBridge.kt:182)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
aerospike-kafka_connector-1  |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

However its not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Error seems pretty clear. `map` types won't work with Avro

Comment: Avro has `map` data type and am able to produce messages containing map type using a custom producer. The issue seem to be from the Aeropsike connector.

Comment: Right. As the error says, `at com.aerospike.connect.kafka.outbound.parser... assertOnlyValidTypes`

Comment: The schema is fixed, by the way, where `msg`  for write operations can only be a string. You cannot add extra fields and get them written to the database - https://docs.aerospike.com/connect/kafka/from-asdb/formats/kafka-avro-serialization-format

Comment: `msg` is part of metadata and holds the operation name like 'write', 'delete'. Every Aerospike change notification message contains metadata + payload.

Comment: Okay. My point is that `testmap` field cannot randomly be inserted into the schema, so it's unclear where that would even come from, given that you cannot supply a custom schema to the source connector, anyway, as far as I know

Comment: Schema is provided via file or string. https://docs.aerospike.com/connect/kafka/from-asdb/formats/kafka-avro-serialization-format. Basically the connector will produce message using the schema provided. 
schema = metadata schema + payload schema.

Comment: I can see that, but nowhere does it mention that you can add arbitrary fields

Comment: check 2nd example: https://docs.aerospike.com/connect/kafka/from-asdb/formats/kafka-avro-serialization-format#examples

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Sorry. In any case, the error is clear. You need to contact Aerospike support directly to ask them